# How do I invoke cm-super?

Tags: fonts, installing, computer-modern

I have installed `cm-super` from the command line in Ubuntu.

I can see the `.pfb` files in `usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super`.

I am still not sure how to invoke them in LaTeX.

This page:
http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super/INSTALL
indicates that I have to manually update updmap files? Really? Is it that complicated?

Do I need to make sure of the presence of anything other than the .pfb files?

Comment: What do you mean "installed from the command line"? If you did `apt-get install cm-super` then the neccessary `updmap` calls should have been executed automatically.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. So it should be on there, I guess. So my question is how do I invoke those fonts in LaTeX? I tried \usepackage{cm-super} but got an error message.

Comment: What happens if you compile a document with cm fonts? Normally, the cm super fonts should just be used automatically.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the cm-super fonts are correctly installed they will be used automatically as soon as you try to use the computer modern fonts with T1-encoding. There is no need to invoke them in a special way. Try this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

Then check the log-file. With cm-super you should see that at the end a cm-super font is mentioned:

```
J:/MiKTeX2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb
```

Without cm-super there would be a `.pk` at this place.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you. This is very clear. cm-super is clearly in the log.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining that `sf` means `super`...

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to all these discussions in this site. I was really facing troubles in removing the type-3 fonts generated in the pdf because of PStricks codes. Ultimately I could get rid of these problems after installing the cm-Super package. I would like to share the steps which I followed for my Miktex.

1. Go to Miktex package manager and type cm-super in the search bar and press Enter:
   [image: Miktex Package manager]
2. You get the following: 
   [image: CM-Super]
3. Click on Task and then Install.

Additionally i had to use 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
and
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
in the preamble to get rid of type 3 fonts. And while using PStricks codes to generate figures, never use \psdots. This creates some type 3 fonts, because of which you may face problems in uploading your pdf in Scholarone manuscripts site and other such sites.

Answer (score 8):

with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble they are taken by default. Running the example with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

has the embedded cm-super font:

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdffonts Namenlos-4.pdf
name                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
-------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
EOEABK+SFRM1000      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
```

However, using the Latin Modern Fonts may make more sense here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: Why *may make more sense*? I am trying to know if I must load it.

Comment: it has some corrections to cm