# Forcing cm-super usage/installation

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Is there any way of forcing users to have cm-super installed? I mean, something like `\usepackage{cm-super}` or equivalent? I want to make sure that all my colleagues produce high-quality PDFs with pdflatex.

I know there is a way to check whether cm-super is installed, [mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super).

Comment: It makes more sense to use `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Latin Modern fonts are derived from Computer Modern

Comment: Cyrillic is mandatory, and it's not included in lmodern.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But there are nowadays other possibilities, e.g. using LuaLaTeX and _any_ useful OpenType font.

Comment: What do you mean with "forcing"? Should they get an error if the package is not there?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would be perfect. Or warning at least, if throwing error is not feasible.

Comment: Load microtype. Or check with \IfFileExits for one of the file of the package.