# babel cyrillic not working in MikTex

Tags: cyrillic

I know there are many questions and answers about babel and Cyrillic, I tried them all, but none works. I am using MikTex 2.9 and open the pdf file either with Foxit Reader or with PDF-XChange Editor, but, since I am writing a lecture text, it should work with all pdf readers.
Here is my minimal example (copied from one of the answers to the topic "cyrillic" I tried) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
Text in English
\par
 \textcyrillic{Текст на русском языке}
\end{document}
```

What I get are some question marks in place of the cyrillic letters 
Thanks in advance for any answer 
Here is the output:  
[image: No cyrillic to be seen] 
Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.11)  20 JAN 2020 20:00
entering extended mode
**./TestRussian.tex
(TestRussian.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\t2aenc.def"
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0100 (decimal 256)
   defining Unicode char U+0101 (decimal 257)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+0108 (decimal 264)
   defining Unicode char U+0109 (decimal 265)
   defining Unicode char U+010A (decimal 266)
   defining Unicode char U+010B (decimal 267)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0112 (decimal 274)
   defining Unicode char U+0113 (decimal 275)
   defining Unicode char U+0114 (decimal 276)
   defining Unicode char U+0115 (decimal 277)
   defining Unicode char U+0116 (decimal 278)
   defining Unicode char U+0117 (decimal 279)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011C (decimal 284)
   defining Unicode char U+011D (decimal 285)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0120 (decimal 288)
   defining Unicode char U+0121 (decimal 289)
   defining Unicode char U+0122 (decimal 290)
   defining Unicode char U+0123 (decimal 291)
   defining Unicode char U+0124 (decimal 292)
   defining Unicode char U+0125 (decimal 293)
   defining Unicode char U+0128 (decimal 296)
   defining Unicode char U+0129 (decimal 297)
   defining Unicode char U+012A (decimal 298)
   defining Unicode char U+012B (decimal 299)
   defining Unicode char U+012C (decimal 300)
   defining Unicode char U+012D (decimal 301)
   defining Unicode char U+012E (decimal 302)
   defining Unicode char U+012F (decimal 303)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0134 (decimal 308)
   defining Unicode char U+0135 (decimal 309)
   defining Unicode char U+0136 (decimal 310)
   defining Unicode char U+0137 (decimal 311)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013B (decimal 315)
   defining Unicode char U+013C (decimal 316)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0145 (decimal 325)
   defining Unicode char U+0146 (decimal 326)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+014C (decimal 332)
   defining Unicode char U+014D (decimal 333)
   defining Unicode char U+014E (decimal 334)
   defining Unicode char U+014F (decimal 335)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0156 (decimal 342)
   defining Unicode char U+0157 (decimal 343)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015C (decimal 348)
   defining Unicode char U+015D (decimal 349)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+0168 (decimal 360)
   defining Unicode char U+0169 (decimal 361)
   defining Unicode char U+016A (decimal 362)
   defining Unicode char U+016B (decimal 363)
   defining Unicode char U+016C (decimal 364)
   defining Unicode char U+016D (decimal 365)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0172 (decimal 370)
   defining Unicode char U+0173 (decimal 371)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+01CD (decimal 461)
   defining Unicode char U+01CE (decimal 462)
   defining Unicode char U+01CF (decimal 463)
   defining Unicode char U+01D0 (decimal 464)
   defining Unicode char U+01D1 (decimal 465)
   defining Unicode char U+01D2 (decimal 466)
   defining Unicode char U+01D3 (decimal 467)
   defining Unicode char U+01D4 (decimal 468)
   defining Unicode char U+01E2 (decimal 482)
   defining Unicode char U+01E3 (decimal 483)
   defining Unicode char U+01E6 (decimal 486)
   defining Unicode char U+01E7 (decimal 487)
   defining Unicode char U+01E8 (decimal 488)
   defining Unicode char U+01E9 (decimal 489)
   defining Unicode char U+01EA (decimal 490)
   defining Unicode char U+01EB (decimal 491)
   defining Unicode char U+01F0 (decimal 496)
   defining Unicode char U+01F4 (decimal 500)
   defining Unicode char U+01F5 (decimal 501)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+0232 (decimal 562)
   defining Unicode char U+0233 (decimal 563)
   defining Unicode char U+1E02 (decimal 7682)
   defining Unicode char U+1E03 (decimal 7683)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2010 (decimal 8208)
   defining Unicode char U+2011 (decimal 8209)
   defining Unicode char U+2012 (decimal 8210)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2015 (decimal 8213)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
   defining Unicode char U+1E20 (decimal 7712)
   defining Unicode char U+1E21 (decimal 7713)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
Now handling font encoding T2A ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T2A
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t2aenc.dfu"
File: t2aenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0400 (decimal 1024)
   defining Unicode char U+0401 (decimal 1025)
   defining Unicode char U+0402 (decimal 1026)
   defining Unicode char U+0403 (decimal 1027)
   defining Unicode char U+0404 (decimal 1028)
   defining Unicode char U+0405 (decimal 1029)
   defining Unicode char U+0406 (decimal 1030)
   defining Unicode char U+0407 (decimal 1031)
   defining Unicode char U+0408 (decimal 1032)
   defining Unicode char U+0409 (decimal 1033)
   defining Unicode char U+040A (decimal 1034)
   defining Unicode char U+040B (decimal 1035)
   defining Unicode char U+040C (decimal 1036)
   defining Unicode char U+040D (decimal 1037)
   defining Unicode char U+040E (decimal 1038)
   defining Unicode char U+040F (decimal 1039)
   defining Unicode char U+0410 (decimal 1040)
   defining Unicode char U+0411 (decimal 1041)
   defining Unicode char U+0412 (decimal 1042)
   defining Unicode char U+0413 (decimal 1043)
   defining Unicode char U+0414 (decimal 1044)
   defining Unicode char U+0415 (decimal 1045)
   defining Unicode char U+0416 (decimal 1046)
   defining Unicode char U+0417 (decimal 1047)
   defining Unicode char U+0418 (decimal 1048)
   defining Unicode char U+0419 (decimal 1049)
   defining Unicode char U+041A (decimal 1050)
   defining Unicode char U+041B (decimal 1051)
   defining Unicode char U+041C (decimal 1052)
   defining Unicode char U+041D (decimal 1053)
   defining Unicode char U+041E (decimal 1054)
   defining Unicode char U+041F (decimal 1055)
   defining Unicode char U+0420 (decimal 1056)
   defining Unicode char U+0421 (decimal 1057)
   defining Unicode char U+0422 (decimal 1058)
   defining Unicode char U+0423 (decimal 1059)
   defining Unicode char U+0424 (decimal 1060)
   defining Unicode char U+0425 (decimal 1061)
   defining Unicode char U+0426 (decimal 1062)
   defining Unicode char U+0427 (decimal 1063)
   defining Unicode char U+0428 (decimal 1064)
   defining Unicode char U+0429 (decimal 1065)
   defining Unicode char U+042A (decimal 1066)
   defining Unicode char U+042B (decimal 1067)
   defining Unicode char U+042C (decimal 1068)
   defining Unicode char U+042D (decimal 1069)
   defining Unicode char U+042E (decimal 1070)
   defining Unicode char U+042F (decimal 1071)
   defining Unicode char U+0430 (decimal 1072)
   defining Unicode char U+0431 (decimal 1073)
   defining Unicode char U+0432 (decimal 1074)
   defining Unicode char U+0433 (decimal 1075)
   defining Unicode char U+0434 (decimal 1076)
   defining Unicode char U+0435 (decimal 1077)
   defining Unicode char U+0436 (decimal 1078)
   defining Unicode char U+0437 (decimal 1079)
   defining Unicode char U+0438 (decimal 1080)
   defining Unicode char U+0439 (decimal 1081)
   defining Unicode char U+043A (decimal 1082)
   defining Unicode char U+043B (decimal 1083)
   defining Unicode char U+043C (decimal 1084)
   defining Unicode char U+043D (decimal 1085)
   defining Unicode char U+043E (decimal 1086)
   defining Unicode char U+043F (decimal 1087)
   defining Unicode char U+0440 (decimal 1088)
   defining Unicode char U+0441 (decimal 1089)
   defining Unicode char U+0442 (decimal 1090)
   defining Unicode char U+0443 (decimal 1091)
   defining Unicode char U+0444 (decimal 1092)
   defining Unicode char U+0445 (decimal 1093)
   defining Unicode char U+0446 (decimal 1094)
   defining Unicode char U+0447 (decimal 1095)
   defining Unicode char U+0448 (decimal 1096)
   defining Unicode char U+0449 (decimal 1097)
   defining Unicode char U+044A (decimal 1098)
   defining Unicode char U+044B (decimal 1099)
   defining Unicode char U+044C (decimal 1100)
   defining Unicode char U+044D (decimal 1101)
   defining Unicode char U+044E (decimal 1102)
   defining Unicode char U+044F (decimal 1103)
   defining Unicode char U+0450 (decimal 1104)
   defining Unicode char U+0451 (decimal 1105)
   defining Unicode char U+0452 (decimal 1106)
   defining Unicode char U+0453 (decimal 1107)
   defining Unicode char U+0454 (decimal 1108)
   defining Unicode char U+0455 (decimal 1109)
   defining Unicode char U+0456 (decimal 1110)
   defining Unicode char U+0457 (decimal 1111)
   defining Unicode char U+0458 (decimal 1112)
   defining Unicode char U+0459 (decimal 1113)
   defining Unicode char U+045A (decimal 1114)
   defining Unicode char U+045B (decimal 1115)
   defining Unicode char U+045C (decimal 1116)
   defining Unicode char U+045D (decimal 1117)
   defining Unicode char U+045E (decimal 1118)
   defining Unicode char U+045F (decimal 1119)
   defining Unicode char U+0490 (decimal 1168)
   defining Unicode char U+0491 (decimal 1169)
   defining Unicode char U+0492 (decimal 1170)
   defining Unicode char U+0493 (decimal 1171)
   defining Unicode char U+0496 (decimal 1174)
   defining Unicode char U+0497 (decimal 1175)
   defining Unicode char U+0498 (decimal 1176)
   defining Unicode char U+0499 (decimal 1177)
   defining Unicode char U+049A (decimal 1178)
   defining Unicode char U+049B (decimal 1179)
   defining Unicode char U+049C (decimal 1180)
   defining Unicode char U+049D (decimal 1181)
   defining Unicode char U+04A0 (decimal 1184)
   defining Unicode char U+04A1 (decimal 1185)
   defining Unicode char U+04A2 (decimal 1186)
   defining Unicode char U+04A3 (decimal 1187)
   defining Unicode char U+04A4 (decimal 1188)
   defining Unicode char U+04A5 (decimal 1189)
   defining Unicode char U+04AA (decimal 1194)
   defining Unicode char U+04AB (decimal 1195)
   defining Unicode char U+04AE (decimal 1198)
   defining Unicode char U+04AF (decimal 1199)
   defining Unicode char U+04B0 (decimal 1200)
   defining Unicode char U+04B1 (decimal 1201)
   defining Unicode char U+04B2 (decimal 1202)
   defining Unicode char U+04B3 (decimal 1203)
   defining Unicode char U+04B6 (decimal 1206)
   defining Unicode char U+04B7 (decimal 1207)
   defining Unicode char U+04B8 (decimal 1208)
   defining Unicode char U+04B9 (decimal 1209)
   defining Unicode char U+04BA (decimal 1210)
   defining Unicode char U+04BB (decimal 1211)
   defining Unicode char U+04C0 (decimal 1216)
   defining Unicode char U+04C1 (decimal 1217)
   defining Unicode char U+04C2 (decimal 1218)
   defining Unicode char U+04D0 (decimal 1232)
   defining Unicode char U+04D1 (decimal 1233)
   defining Unicode char U+04D2 (decimal 1234)
   defining Unicode char U+04D3 (decimal 1235)
   defining Unicode char U+04D4 (decimal 1236)
   defining Unicode char U+04D5 (decimal 1237)
   defining Unicode char U+04D6 (decimal 1238)
   defining Unicode char U+04D7 (decimal 1239)
   defining Unicode char U+04D8 (decimal 1240)
   defining Unicode char U+04D9 (decimal 1241)
   defining Unicode char U+04DA (decimal 1242)
   defining Unicode char U+04DB (decimal 1243)
   defining Unicode char U+04DC (decimal 1244)
   defining Unicode char U+04DD (decimal 1245)
   defining Unicode char U+04DE (decimal 1246)
   defining Unicode char U+04DF (decimal 1247)
   defining Unicode char U+04E2 (decimal 1250)
   defining Unicode char U+04E3 (decimal 1251)
   defining Unicode char U+04E4 (decimal 1252)
   defining Unicode char U+04E5 (decimal 1253)
   defining Unicode char U+04E6 (decimal 1254)
   defining Unicode char U+04E7 (decimal 1255)
   defining Unicode char U+04E8 (decimal 1256)
   defining Unicode char U+04E9 (decimal 1257)
   defining Unicode char U+04EC (decimal 1260)
   defining Unicode char U+04ED (decimal 1261)
   defining Unicode char U+04EE (decimal 1262)
   defining Unicode char U+04EF (decimal 1263)
   defining Unicode char U+04F0 (decimal 1264)
   defining Unicode char U+04F1 (decimal 1265)
   defining Unicode char U+04F2 (decimal 1266)
   defining Unicode char U+04F3 (decimal 1267)
   defining Unicode char U+04F4 (decimal 1268)
   defining Unicode char U+04F5 (decimal 1269)
   defining Unicode char U+04F8 (decimal 1272)
   defining Unicode char U+04F9 (decimal 1273)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2017/05/19 3.10 The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-russian\russianb.ldf"
Language: russian 2017/08/12 1.3j Russian support for the Babel system

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2017/05/19 3.10 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 120.
Package babel Info: Default for \cyrdash is provided on input line 157.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/01/24 v3.3q English support from the babel system
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) (TestRussian.aux)
\openout1 = `TestRussian.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T2A/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T2A+cmr on input line 6.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\t2acmr.fd"
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--9

 []

[1

{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (TestRussian.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1684 strings out of 493323
 17563 string characters out of 3139069
 75566 words of memory out of 3000000
 5259 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5200 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,23p,184b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKT
eX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\lh\lh-t2a\dpi600\larm1000.pk> <C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec
\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on TestRussian.pdf (1 page, 5878 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Show your log-file.

Comment: Output looks fine here as well (pdfLaTeX, fully updated MikTeX 2.9 on Win 10). Can you show the `.log` file of this MWE and an image of the output, please?

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike and moewe - I have to find out how to send the log file

Comment: Copy the log in your question.

Comment: Did it - sorry, long wire (lange Leitung)

Comment: You should install the `cm-super` package for MiKTeX, both as Admin and User.

Comment: thanks egreg. Yes, that seems to solve the problem. I looked here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super and there is a .pk at the end. Now I have to find out how to install the cm-super package in Miktex.

Answer (score -1):

Try to write separately

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
Текст на русском языке
\end{document}
```

Comment: The separate `babel` calls will just result in an `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.` error (and I think the `\usepackage[english]{babel}` will be ignored meaning that the main language of the document is Russian).