# Latex Type 3 Font Issue in windows 10

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I am trying to submit my manuscript but it gives me an issue with type 3 font in Latex. I have installed cm-super package and also followed the steps referred [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super). I am pasting the last portion of log file. Anyone can help in resolving this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mobeen, welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly is your issue? The LaTeX output seems to be fine.

Comment: the wasy font is a bitmap. Do you have the wasy-type1 package installed?

Comment: you are using bitmap version of the wasy font, do you need this font? It is available in type1 format `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/wasy-type1/wasy10.pfb` in texlive, someone should be able to help you fix your miktex configuration to use it

Comment: @TobiBS the log shows the bitmap wasy font being used

Comment: Thanks everyone. What is the easiest way to fix this issue? I mean any configuration issue or any package issue?

Comment: I am using \usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym} in my code because I am using integrals. Is it because of this package I am getting font error?

Comment: Please post your `MWE` for further analyzing...